# Problem with using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column (RCV1.ECCValue) in a table which 99% of the time has a constant string format- example being:

T0-11.86-273

the middle part of the two hyphens is a percentage. I'm using the below sql to obtain this figure which is working fine and returns 11.86 on the above example. **when** the data in that table is in above format

```
'Percentage' = round(SUBSTRING(RCV1.ECCValue,CHARINDEX('-',RCV1.ECCValue)+1, CHARINDEX('-',RCV1.ECCValue,CHARINDEX('-',RCV1.ECCValue)+1) -CHARINDEX('-',RCV1.ECCValue)-1),2) ,
```

However...this table is updated from an external source and very occasionally the separators differ, for example:

T0-11.86_273

when this occurs I get the error:

*Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.*

I'm very new to SQL and have got myself out of many challenges but this one has got me stuck. Any help would be mostly appreciated. Is there a better way to extract this percentage value?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you know if the percentage will always start from the 4th character? And will it always have 2 decimal points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace '_' with '-' to string in CHARINDEX while specifying length to the substring

```
'Percentage' = round(SUBSTRING(RCV1.ECCValue,CHARINDEX('-',RCV1.ECCValue)+1, CHARINDEX('-',replace(RCV1.ECCValue,'_','-'),CHARINDEX('-',RCV1.ECCValue)+1) -CHARINDEX('-',RCV1.ECCValue)-1),2) ,
```

Comment: This solution is perfect for what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the structure of these strings, you can try `parsename`

```
select round(parsename(translate(replace('T0-11.86_273','.',''),'-_','..'),2), 2)/100
```

**Breakdown of steps**

- Replace `.` character in the percentage value with empty string using `replace`.
- Replace `-` or `_`, whichever is present, with `.` using `translate`.
- Parse the second element using `parsename`.
- Round it up to 2 digits, which will also
  automatically cast it to the desired numeric type.
- Divide by 100
  to restore the number as percentage.

[**Documentation & Gotchas**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Each%20part%20of%20the%20%27object_name%27%20string%20is%20type%20sysname%20which%20is%20equivalent%20to%20nvarchar(128)%20or%20256%20bytes.%20If%20any%20part%20of%20the%20string%20exceeds%20256%20bytes%2C%20PARSENAME%20will%20return%20NULL%20for%20that%20part%20as%20it%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20sysname.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULLIF` to null out such values

```sql
round(
  SUBSTRING(
    RCV1.ECCValue,
    NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', RCV1.ECCValue), 0) + 1,
    NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-',
              RCV1.ECCValue,
              NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', RCV1.ECCValue), 0) + 1
       ), 0)
       - NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', RCV1.ECCValue), 0) - 1
  ),
2)
```

I strongly recommend that you place the repeated values in `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to avoid having to repeat yourself. And do use whitespace, it's free.